# sumif formula to calculate values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I have this data set where I am using this formula to calculate the outstanding course fee but when I am putting the amount received its not deducting the remaining amount from the total course fee and showing in the next record. I am not able to work this out with sumif formula, any help will be highly appreciated.

=IF(AND(ISBLANK(A5)),"",VLOOKUP(A5,Student_Registration!$B$5:$H$2000,7,0)-SUMIF($A$5,A5,$I$5))

Sample worksheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1roEXEuBBwHU8lKV_QruY6hVjYOOkpwAwAI5x8yuYfZ8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Column G and Column I already have value to be used, why don't you use the following simplified formula to obtain the expected outcome?
What you need is to used to formula to populate the value in Column I, hope it will help.

```
=G5-SUMIF($A$5:A5,A5,$I$5:I5)
```

[image]

Comment: it worked, thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome, glad it solve your problem :)